# Sentence ending in a preposition

Tags: prepositions

> **It was a prospective, randomised clinical trial in which 245 volunteers participated in.**

Does the above read / sound correct?

Would it be better to say:

> It was a prospective, randomised clinical trial which 245 volunteers participated in.

or even:

> It was a prospective, randomised clinical trial in which 245 volunteers participated.

Comment: The first sentence has a superfluous _in_. The second and third sentences are grammatical, with the third being more formal.

Comment: Ok that was very useful, thanks!

Comment: https://quoteinvestigator.com/2012/07/04/churchill-preposition/  Up with which...